# List of UserAgent String Values

Tags: asp.net, mobile-website

I am trying to determine what kind of interface to show to a user. If a user is visiting my site with a touch screen phone, I want to show them one interface, otherwise, I want to show them another.

Does anyone know of a list of UserAgent string values so I can do this check? I know I can check for the iPhone using the following code in ASP.NET:

Request.UserAgent.IndexOf("iPhone", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)

However, I would really like to find a list for other similar phones like

Palm Pre
Blackberry Thunder
etc.

Comment: trying to figure this out too, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6066848/mobile-device-detection-for-rendering-rich-web-content

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Mobile Device Browser File](http://mdbf.codeplex.com/) might be of some help. Example: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MixMobileWebSitesWithASPNETMVCAndTheMobileBrowserDefinitionFile.aspx

Comment: Also has the advantage that it gives you a full set of capabilites for the devices, which is something that the user agent string doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer [WURFL](http://ct=result&usg=AFQjCNGxtl_2pL6HZpO2I9TZtooU7zXkig), it is most up date database. And you can use .NET API [Marg.Wurfl](http://www.mihavalencic.com/wurflapi/).

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know at present,there are 147 different webphone browsers if you count versions as being different and 2438 makes/models (Samsung has about 180).
  Having just a list i think is useless as there are android phones that do not report that name in the userAgent string; which implies that maybe nothing else is useful with that string.
  Instead,use a set of simple PC-based browser tests and let the failure be "by gollie i am going to treat this user as a webphone".
  Safe to test any "standard" browser IE6 to IE9 (have not tested beyond that) or mozilla; at fall thru test for Safari, Chrome or Opera. Treat those last 3 as webphone, and fail of those tests, treat user as a webphone.
  Even IE5 acts fairly decently on moer "modern" web pages!
  So one set of pages for standard, and another for limited, junkie (Safari and Opera are in both classes), or extremely variable webphones.
  The lowest, junkiest webphone i have seen is the TracFone LG800G; rather limited memory and worse, limited page size.
  Do not ask what those limits are as nobody is talking,but they are small compared to anything else.